# MediaWiki: Getting "readapidenied" error instead of login token

Tags: api, authentication, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

That's a quite puzzling problem. I've multiple MediaWiki installations. In this specific case: Version 1.34.

Now I can login to all of these MediaWikis. Everything works fine.

Now I can access all of these MediaWikis via API --- EXCEPT ONE. The strange thing is: All of them are configured almost identical. I even copied the configuration from one wiki where everything was working to the second wiki.

To be more precise. If I send ...

```
/wikiA/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json&type=login
```

... I get a very reasonable answer, e.g.:

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"tokens":{"logintoken":"37ec2e690eeb48a10ac66b2ccbca2b576000f9f4+\\"}}}
```

If I send ...

```
/wikiB/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json&type=login
```

... I get the following answer, e.g.:

```
{"error":{"code":"readapidenied","info":"You need read permission to use this module.","*":"See http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/wikiB/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."}}
```

This can be reproduced using any web browser.

Q: What could be the reason that on this `wikiB` I even can't access the normal login module? It can't be the configuration. It's almost completely identical. It can't be the source code. I ran a diff on the PHP files and found no significant differences. What could be wrong here? It seems it must be something with the database. But how do I approach this? Does anyone have an idea? I would appreciate it very much if you could help!

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the data base: No difference. I did more research using google: And found a bug report.

It's a bug in MediaWiki. They provided an official software release with THAT kind of bug.

It turnes out there is a 1.34.0 version and a 1.34.1 version. My WikiA has 1.34.1 while WikiB had 1.34.0. After copying this one single file `includes/api/ApiQuery.php` from WikiA to WikiB and everything worked fine.

https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/c/mediawiki/core/+/580097/